# How to get the position of LUKS header by `bgrep`

Tags: grep, luks

I tried to get the position of LUKS header:

`grep -a -b -P --only-matching 'LUKS\xba\xbe' /dev/sdb`

It is out of memory.

Some sugest me use 'bgrep' instead, but I don't how to make it work.

`bgrep -A 20 'LUKS\xba\xbe' /dev/sda`
`./bgrep: invalid 2-hex-digit byte value: 'LU'`

So how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

`grep` tends to run out of memory since it reads until end-of-line, but in binary data there might not be an end-of-line for a long time. You could still use grep by grepping chunks of smaller-than-memory size, roughly:

```
# dd bs=1M iflag=fullblock if=/dev/sdb skip=X count=Y | grep ...
```

Rinse and repeat for all chunks. If you're not sure about whether the data will be aligned properly, make the chunks overlap some (next X=X+Y-1).

Alternatively, `strings` would *probably* avoid the running out of memory part (very long lines of printable ASCII are unlikely to appear). Then you have a list of offsets to check. These can be false matches since `strings` excludes the `\xba\xbe` part.

```
# strings -t d -n 4 /dev/sdb | grep 'LUKS$'
11534336 LUKS
23068672 LUKS
34603008 LUKS
# losetup --find --show --offset=23068672 /dev/sdb
/dev/loop9
# cryptsetup luksDump /dev/loop9
```

Tools like `testdisk` or `binwalk` (with a [custom magic signature](https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk/wiki/Creating-Custom-Signatures)) might be able to locate LUKS headers more efficiently. But for a quick hack, `strings` usually works well enough.

Comment: No, `strings -t d -n 4 /dev/sdb | grep LUKS` lists too many iterms about LUKS even out of the number Terminal window can contain, how can I make it print only LUKS header for LUKS partition?

Comment: @Maggicmuojet Not really possible with strings... Terminal window? Redirect output to a file, and script it. Otherwise, if you're sure about the cipher, you could also e.g. `grep -B 1 xts-plain` (for luks1 headers, for luks2 you want `strings -t d -n 100 | grep '"type":"luks2"'` and substract 4096).

Comment: `sudo grep -B 1 xts-plain /dev/sdb` Then a message: `Binary file /dev/sdb matches`

Comment: Where to bit /dev/sdb to `strings -t d -n 100 | grep '"type":"luks2"'`?

Comment: Is there any1 in, and any1 help?

Comment: `strings -t d -n 100 /dev/sdb | grep ...`,